# How do I prevent PhoneGap Build from asking for location permissions? (iPhone)

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have implemented every documentation and fix that I can find to no avail.

I want the app to grab the location when a button is tapped.

Every fix I try has one of two outcomes:
 1) A jumbled mess of a permission request appears every time.
 2) The latitude and longitude are reported as '0'.

No matter where I call the getCurrentPosition() I am presented a jumbled mess of a permission request (even though on first-load the app requests it).

I am able to limit the permission request to once per session, but it is still an ugly mess and I can't believe that there wouldn't be a way to avoid it.

**config.xml -- UPDATED using ConfiGAP**

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-transparent" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="false" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="internalOnly" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000"/>
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="LoadingDialog" value=","/> 
<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<gap:platform name="ios" />
<gap:platform name="android" />
<gap:platform name="winphone" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"  />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"  />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />
    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIStatusBarHidden">
        <true/>
    </gap:config-file>
        <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance">
        <false/>
    </gap:config-file>
```

**app.js**

```
$("#punches").on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (pos) {
        var lat = pos.coords.latitude,
            lon = pos.coords.longitude;

        $("#latitude").val(lat);
        $("#longitude").val(lon);
    });
});
```

Tired of banging my head against a wall for something that I feel should be so much easier than I am making of it.

**ANY** help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Permission in "alert form" are because the cordova.js library is not being correctly included. So the events are not correctly mapping. Are you using phonegap build  or cordova-cli to build your app?

Comment: We are using the PhoneGap Build service.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
var lon = pos.coords.longitude;
```

?

I'd also make sure I specified the version of the core geolocation plugin just so you know it works with your versions of PGB.

Comment: Comma separated is also valid variable declaration.

Also, please see the updated config.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely embarrassing...but it appears that all I was missing was:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

I put this in my `index.html` and the double-permission is now gone and Latitude/Longitude are being reported appropriately.

I apologize for the question.  Thanks to those whom helped.